# How to structure external API calls for Node.js, express, ejs routing?

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes, axios

```
//API Call one
function receiveLocation(){
    axios({
        "method":"GET",
        "url":"https://ip-geo-location.p.rapidapi.com/ip/check",

        ...

        })
        .then((response)=>{
        return response.data.country.name;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
       })
}
//API Call two
//API Call three

console.log(receiveLocation());

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    var location = receiveLocation();//
    //Then render all the data from my API calls such as location, currency, 
    //etc. in my landing page. Also use that data on the backend.
    res.render("landing",{location:location});
});
```

I am currently trying to make a website that uses multiple API calls to get information such as location, currency, and other things of a user who loads the website.

I am attempting to receive all the information from the different API calls as I go through the get request route that allows a user to see the landing page. Firstly, I am not even sure if this is allowed. If it is allowed/standard practice, what am I doing wrong in this example. I am attempting to call a function that in the get route to the root page that returns the country of a visiting user. But after doing some console.log() debugging I see that that information is never being received in the get route. Last note: I want to use the info from the API calls both to change what the user sees, and for some calculations that would need to be run on the backend.

If this is not allowed/not standard practice, may someone explain what I should do instead/point in the right direction as to what I should learn to get a better understanding of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying at the moment to do is not standard practice, you should lookup MVC for Express,there you will learn how to structure your backend code so that the GET Routes will be used as Views ( these will be your server getting some public files like html,css,javascript that will be passed some information from the Controllers,this is done by using some server-side renders like EJS).
I recommend taking this Udemy course https://www.udemy.com/course/nodejs-the-complete-guide/ for a full understanding,but if you don't have the time,lookup node.js mvc with express, there is plently information about this.